# Did Harry ever visit the Dursleys in adulthood?

Tags: harry-potter

I was wondering whether Harry ever thought to visit the Dursleys after the war against Voldemort was won. He might have wanted to know how they were, how was their life while they were in hiding, etc.

According to an answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4716/4725), J.K. Rowling said that Harry would see Dudley, but I'd like to know if he ever saw his aunt and uncle again, especially after he saw Snape's memories in the pensieve and found out a bit more about her.

Comment: I don't think Vernon and Petunia still hate Harry, as in the start of the 7th film, Dudley was more friendly to Harry. Even in the deleted scenes Petunia regretted calling "freak" to her sister. I think Harry visits the Dursleys every weekend even if JKR does not say so.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no canon info regarding Harry visiting the Dursleys. Nothing on Wikia, books, or JKR quote sources.

We can infer that the answer is most likely "no" from some info:

> However, I know that after Dudley’s brave attempt at reconciliation at the start of Deathly Hallows, the two cousins would have remained on ‘Christmas Card’ terms for the rest of their lives, and that Harry would have taken his family to visit Dudley’s when they were in the neighbourhood (occasions dreaded by James, Albus and Lily). (Src: [jkrowling.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20080205011244/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=26))
>
> Harry and Dudley would still see each other enough to be on Christmas-card terms, but they would visit more out of a sense of duty **and sit in silence so that their children could see their cousins**. (src: [J.K. Rowling's comments at Carnegie Hall](http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1572399/harry-potter-author-jk-rowling-outs-dumbledore.jhtml))

Given that Harry has a much better relationship with Dudley (as per the scene where they are leaving #4 Privet Drive in DH) than with his Aunt/Uncle, and even that only lends itself to visiting with kids so they play with relatives - **Harry would have zero reason to bother visiting the Dursleys**.

Answer (score 3):

I think that as Harry got older, the rift would likely have deepened. It's one thing to suffer through it as a child...but as an adult he would have seen their behavior from an entirely different perspective and that likely would have made things between them worse, not better. Dudley tried. Dudley was a spoiled child feeding off his parents crap. He can be forgiven. What the adults did, however, was so horrible that I doubt the rift could have been healed. I don't think there is any coming back from that kind of abuse.

Harry married into a large and loving family. He would have had no need, emotional or otherwise, to both with those people ever again. He may have asked Dudley about them, making polite conversation, but it's likely that if he feels any regret there it's for what might have been rather than a desire for reconciliation.

Comment: This seems very plausible, but can you provide evidence from the books or movies to back it up?

Answer (score -3):

If you read the play you would know he kept in contact with his aunt and Dudley that's how he ended up with the blanket his mother wrapped him in before she died. So to answer your question yes he kept in contact and any one who says other wise have no idea what the heck they are talking about .

Comment: I don't think the play you are thinking of was written when this question was asked in 2012.

Comment: Nope but when people answer back in 2017 it was. That's what I was commenting on which is why I responded like that lol.

Comment: Then this is not an answer to the question. When you have a little more reputation, you will be able to comment on other people's answers.

Comment: I think that your answer is too personal and impolite. Not enough to flag it as rude or abuse but I do not think it is necessary to criticize other answers in the way you did. You could have done with a polite comment.